# get derived classes access the member data and functions of each other

Tags: c++, inheritance

how to make derived classes access the member data and functions of each other. both classes are inherited from base class as pure abstract.

here my scenario

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        // need to use a2
        // need to use func
    }
private:
    int a1;
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        // need to use a1
    }
    void func(){}
private:
    int a2;
};
```

Comment: You don't have any derivation here. Your forgot the base class clauses.

Comment: Strange idea... But you can store reference/pointer for needed class in used class (reference on Derived2 object in Derived1 and so on). Also, you can rewrite your classes to template classes...

Comment: @SebastianRedl .. i missed that. i updated it thanks

Comment: Why would you want doing so? If you want access to it so much, either you pass it as a parameter to the function, or you can just declare these variables in the base class as you use both in the derived classes.

Comment: First: It is a broken design. Second: You can't do it. Your class Derived2 has no member a1. That's it!

Comment: @Klaus .. that why i need help. what's the proper design to achieve this

Comment: You have to tell us which *problem* you want to solve! You give us an example of a non working realization of your solution. But to find a solution which solves your real problem, we need an idea of the real problem.

Comment: @MORTAL more information necessary. The instance of Derived1 has to locate an instance of Derived2 to use some members and vice versa, right? Are they related somehow? There could be many instances of both classes.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky ... yes indeed that the case. is there any way to get instances

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to re-think your design. There will be no memory allocated to a1 for Derived2's object and similarly for a2 and Derived1. What you are asking is equivalent to saying, both cat and dog are animals, I want to use cat::whiskers in dog.
You probably need this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
     int a1;
     int a2;
     void func(){}
};
class Derived1 : public Derived 
{
public:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        // can use a2 and func here
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Derived
{
public:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        // need to use a1
    }
    void func() override {}
};
```

Comment: So you have in Derived1 two members a1. One is Derived1::a1 and one is Derived::a1. What do you think solves this?

Comment: It is still a broken design. If the member a1 relates only to Derived1 what should a base class declare these members? And if a1&a2 are related to the base class, why the derived class only deal with only a subset of these?

Comment: @Klaus The requirements are broken itself. I was not trying to give the correct solution. Infact I don't think it's possible to give a correct solution based on the requirements he suggested. My solution will "just work" for the exact scenario he said.

Comment: Yes, the question shows only a broken solution with a fully broken design which was fixed here. My question to OP was not answered so nobody knows what the code should really achieve...